# Making an HTML form responsive

Tags: html, forms

I'm studying the HTML5 and CSS3 code and I have created my first form.

I have this problem: how can I make my form responsive?

I have this code:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Prenota il Servizio</legend>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="nome">Nome*</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="nome" autofocus required size="30">
</td>
<td>
<label for="cognome">Cognome*</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="cognome" autofocus required size="30">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

But what can I do to make this responsive?

Comment: "Responsive" is too broad a term. Specifically how do you want the form to respond?

Comment: So for responsive i think that i can use the form from desktop, tabelt and smartphone.

Answer (score 4):

In modern Web 3.0 development "Responsive Design" involves CSS3 media queries.

They look something like this:

```
// Smartphone Version

@media (min-width: 200px) {

    form {
          width: 150px;
          height: 500px;
    }

}


// Tablet version

@media (min-width: 700px) {

    form {
          width: 350px;
          height: 500px;
    }

}

// Full computer version

@media (min-width: 1024px) {

    form {
          width: 900px;
          height: 500px;
    }

}
```

This is a very simple example. The principal is, use CSS to detect what kind of screen (or other factor, there are many many) and then apply these style rules (inside the `{…}`) for that screen (or other criteria).

Have a look here for details from Mozilla Dev Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

There is also a starter solution over at http://www.initializr.com (choose the responsive template and build it out).

Comment: If this is what he meant by responsive design then this is a better answer.

Comment: Almost 4 years later and this still helped me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to be reading about the `Form` tag.

Example:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks' for the reply but so, how can i have the colum? And also, with this code is responsive my form? (Sorry but i learn).

Comment: If you'd like to place the separate inputs/labels into different table cells then go for it. Also, the action="" signifies what is performed when the the submit button is pressed. So you would have to code some JavaScript or ASP or something to work with the form.

Comment: Oh yes, yes, i know also about the method (GET or POST). Thank's for your explanation. But, how can i make my form responsive (so, the people can use on desktop or smartphone)?

Comment: If your form works on a PC based browser, it shouldn't have an issue on another platform. In other words, if the backend works, the only difference should be that the layout isn't the same on the two form-factors.

Comment: Mm no, yes if i look the page from my smartphone the layout is not align and i can't use the form with simplicity. I know there is the element style media on css3 but i don't know how can i use to personalizate my form.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/default.asp and
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp should help you with what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>BUG-13</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <style>
    

    .fieldset
    {
    width:50%;
    }
    .form-inline
    {
    height: 11px;
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #928383;
    margin-left: 15px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 360px)
    {
    .fieldset
    {
    font-size: 10px;
    color:red;
    font-size:10px;
    }
    }
    </style>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <fieldset class="form">
      <legend>Prenota il Servizio</legend>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="nome">Nome*</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-inline" type="text" name="nome" autofocus required size="30">
          </td>
          <td>
           <label for="cognome" style="padding-left: 14px;">Cognome*</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input   class="form-inline" type="text" name="cognome" autofocus required size="30">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```